# Redshift Rounding Off Issue

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table which has a numeric(23,2) field that I need to divide to a constant.

My baseline is this aggregation

```
select site, sum(sales) / 1.07 as sales from sales group by site;
```

But when I add another column then compare the total sum across all, I noticed some decimal drop-offs

```
select site, product, sum(sales) / 1.07 as sales from sales group by site, product;
```

Is there like a proper way to handle such in Redshift?

Comment: Please show the current output along with the output you actually want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest dividing *before* doing the sum:

```
select site, product, sum(sales / 1.07) as sales
from sales
group by site, product;
```

Mathematically, this should be equivalent.  However, because numbers are not infinite precision in computers, this may address your issue.